# Angular default value for a mat-cell

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, default

I've tried this:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    {{element.someDate || "N/A" | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</td>
```

and this

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
   {{element.someDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' || "N/A" }} 
</td>
```

This works though, but no use:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
  {{element.someDate || "N/A" }} 
</td>
```

No joy.

How do I set both formatting and a default value for a date cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with Angular CLI: 6.2.5

```
{{(element.someDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') || 'N/A' }}
```